# User agent info is not proper when calling from axios call in node js

Tags: node.js, user-agent, axios

I have two servers. One is my `api server` and other one is my `rendering server`. Both are in node js. When I call any api from my rendering server to my api server using axios and get the `req.headers['user-agent']` in my api server then it gives me only `axios/0.15.2`. But I want the complete user agent info like browser, os, device etc. How do I get those info?

Answer (score 3):

Set a custom header like:

```
var config = {
  headers: {'X-My-Custom-Header': 'Header-Value'}
};

axios.get('https://api.github.com/users/codeheaven-io', config);
axios.post('/save', { firstName: 'Marlon' }, config);
```

https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/69